# How can I do "rake routes" equivalent with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to check defined routes of my ASP.NET MVC applicaiton.
How can I see that all URLs, acceptable verbs, and corresponding action methods are same as what I think?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can checkout is [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It can show you how the routing engine chooses your route for a given URL.

If you want to assert that the routing is set up according to your expectations given your URL schema, you can [write unit tests for your routes](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc%20unit%20test%20routes).

**Reply to comments**

How do you declaratively implement routes in MVC? I always thought they had to compile from C#, but maybe you are using some lib I have never heard of.

Also, you can assert that a given (set of) URL(s), which you do not intend to be routed, is (are) not routed.

Comment: Thank you but I just want to see full set of available routing of my application instead of to assert. Routing is implemented in declarative, so I don't want to assert it. And also you can't assert unintended routes.

Comment: I use normally way. RouteCollection.MapRotue method and [HttpGet/Post/...] attributes and [ActionName()] attribute.

Comment: "rake routes" equivalent makes me notice methods should have [NoAction] or [Http???].